# How to plot a comb?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This type of plot might have a different name, if so kindly point me to a relevant post.

I am trying to plot simple "comb" plot using `geom_segment()`:

```
require(ggplot2)

#dummy data
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(x=sample(1:100,20))

#plot comb
ggplot(data=dat,
       aes(x=x,y=0,xend=x, yend=10)) +
  geom_segment() +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank()) +
  #hide y ticks and label
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=NULL) +
  ylab(NULL)
```

[image]

It seems, so many lines of code for a simple plot, is there other `ggplot` function I am missing?

Comment: Your plot really only has one line of code, the rest is defining a new theme.  The only suggestion I have is to use `geom_vline` instead of `geom_segment`.  Try: `ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=0)) + geom_blank() + geom_vline(aes(xintercept=x), data=dat)
`

Comment: I thought of using `geom_vline`, too. Then I have to use `geom_blank` and still have to hide `y` ticks and labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dunno about ggplot, but why not use `graphics::rug` ?

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- sample(1:100,20)
plot(dat,dat,t='n')
rug(dat)
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Rug is the word I was looking for. There is `geom_rug`, but I can't change the height. Sorry, it has to be `ggplot` solution.

Comment: I'm not a `ggplot` expert but I wouldn't be surprised to find there's some aesthetic or parameter that can be passed via `...` to change the tic-mark height.